# TabLayout selected tab gravity

Tags: android, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport, android-tablayout

`TabLayout` is set up with `ViewPager`, has a lot of tabs, `MODE_SCROLLABLE` and keyline `app:tabContentStart="72dp"`.

When user selects a tab, `TabLayout` tries to scroll the selected tab to the center. I would like the selected tab to be left aligned to keyline, not centered. Is it possible?

Android Design Support Library v22.2.0.

Comment: What did you mean about keyline?

Comment: 'Keyline' is a term used in https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html, in Android Design Support Library it is declared via `app:tabContentStart`.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately the method `calculateScrollXForTab()` of TabLayout is private and then not replaceable by subclasses. Either way you can copy the source TabLayout in your project, then possibly extending it with your class, and change the method `calculateScrollXForTab()` like this:

```
private int calculateScrollXForTab(int position, float positionOffset) {
   if (mMode == MODE_SCROLLABLE) {
      View final selectedChild = mTabStrip.getChildAt(position);
      // LoG.i ("scrollTo" String.valueOf ((int) selectedChild.getLeft()));
      return (int) selectedChild.getLeft();
   }
   return 0;
}
```

This returns the value of the limit on the left of the tab selected, then scrolling is forced to that value. The extreme right tabs will remain fixed in position if selected because the scroll clamps the scrolling to the bounds of the child.

I tried it and it works, although I had to solve two problems with one CompatTextView not found in *android.support.v7.internal.widget* and method `setupWithViewPager()` that does not exist in the source available to me (I think a matter of version)

Answer (score 4):

If I understood your question well, you can subtract the first tab position from the selected tab position. Then, you just set the different as a position for this selected tab.