# how to make selected tab in center

Tags: android

I am facing a problem and i need a solution of it as soon as possible.
I am working on android application.I have 8 tabs I want , when i click one of them then selected tab must come in centre.
 here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="bhitch.bhitch.com.bhitch.CategoryActivity">


    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/image_viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_layout">

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/firsttabstrip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"/>

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/image_viewPager"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"

        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        app:tabGravity="center"
       app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/tab_focus"
        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white">

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="700dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/tabLayout">

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/secondtabstrip"
            android:layout_gravity="top"/>

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>



</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my Activity class

```
public class CategoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ViewPager viewPager;
    CategoryAdapter adapter;
    GridView gridView;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager imageViewPager;
    CategoryAdapter imageAdapter;
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;
    PagerTabStrip firsttabstrip;
    PagerTabStrip secondtabstrip;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_category);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

       viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        imageViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.image_viewPager);
        firsttabstrip=(PagerTabStrip)findViewById(R.id.firsttabstrip);
        secondtabstrip=(PagerTabStrip)findViewById(R.id.secondtabstrip);
     imageAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(this);
        imageViewPager.setAdapter(imageAdapter);


        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        toolbar.setTitle("Category Activity");


        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new HealthFragment(), "Health");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new BeautyFragment(), "Beauty");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new AutomobileFragment(), "Automobile");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new CinemaFragment(), "Cinema");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new FoodFragment(), "Food");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new BeautyFragment(), "Music");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new ElectronicFragment(), "Electronics");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new EducationFragment(), "Education");



        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);



        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        // tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(imageViewPager);




              viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {


            }


                  @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                imageViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
                tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_CENTER);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {


            }
        });


        imageViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
                tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_CENTER);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

this is viewpageradapter class

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> tabTitles =  new ArrayList<>();

    public void addFragments(Fragment fragments , String titles ){

        this.fragments.add(fragments);
        this.tabTitles.add(titles);
    }

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabTitles.get(position);
    }
}
```

1st , 2nd , 7th, 8th tab is not coming in centre when i click on it and rest tabs are coming in centre . I wanna make a circular chain of tab so that when i click any of them then selected tab must come in centre. Thanks in advance.

Comment: follow this answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324828/tablayout-selected-tab-gravity

Comment: its not a solution