# How to set snapping behaviour for TabLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I'm using `TabLayout` to show icon and name of different tabs. With `TabLayout` I'm using `ViewPager` to add `Fragments` per each tab. `TabLayout` with clickable tabs (and they are centered in a middle on click) is working, but I want to implement same functionality as `RecyclerView` `SnapHelper` can do. If I scroll `TabLayout` tabs it will snap view to the center of the screen and select it. This should show `Fragment` under `TabLayout`.

Is there any way how to do it?

This is my custom TabLayout which will center clicked view to the middle.

```
class CenteredTabLayout : TabLayout {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {}

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {}

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {}

    override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, l: Int, t: Int, r: Int, b: Int) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b)
        val firstTab = (getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup).getChildAt(0)
        val lastTab = (getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup).getChildAt((getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup).childCount - 1)
        if (firstTab != null && lastTab != null){
            ViewCompat.setPaddingRelative(getChildAt(0), width / 2 - firstTab.width / 2, 0, width / 2 - lastTab.width / 2, 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[TabLayout selected tab gravity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324828/tablayout-selected-tab-gravity/31480687)

tl;dr With the default TabLayout, you *cannot modify the snapping effect*. Because the method to calculate the distance of its moving `calculateScrollXForTab` is private and cannot be replaced.

I wanted to do some customized snapping with my TabLayout as well. Eventually I gave up, and created my own RecyclerView and adapter for the tabs. I did not need the indicator that is provided by the TabLayout (created my custom indicator). So all I had to do was to implement `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` using my adapter.

Also reading up on how other source code did the scrolling really helped me.

For example, https://github.com/nshmura/RecyclerTabLayout